# How can I insert and delete rows with a parameter array of integer Ids/Keys in MySql using Spring Data/JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I have an array of integers that needs to insert row(s) (if FID does not exists) or delete row(s) (if row exists with an FID that is no longer in the array).

Existing rows in DB:

```
ID | FID
1, 12
1, 13
1, 14
1, 15
1, 16
```

If I pass array [13, 15, 17], then it will delete rows with FID 12,14 & 16 while creating new row 17. Resulting rows will be:

```
ID | FID
1, 13
1, 15
1, 17
```

Comment: I would suggest doing this in a store procedure, where you can create a temporary table with your existent FID, something like this:   DECLARE  temp TABLE (FID int);  INSERT INTO  temp (FID) values (1),(2), (3); --make this dynamyc by adding a parameter to the stored procedure-- Then it would be easy to delete from your real table the difference between both tables, and then find the FID from the temp that doesnt exist in the real table, iterate through them and insert them.

Comment: I know it can be done in proc but I am looking for an alternative, thus the question.